# Changing modifier keys from the command line

Tags: keyboard

As a heavy Emacs user, I like to remap my Caps Lock key to function as the Ctrl key.  There is a convenient dialog in the Keyboard Preference Pane to do that.   But the problem is that this setting gets lost after someone logs into another account that hasn't this preference set.

So is there any way of doing the same as the preference pane dialog from the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating modifier key mappings through defaults command tool](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13598/updating-modifier-key-mappings-through-defaults-command-tool). Although the other question is historically newer, it has a better (actually working) answer.

Answer (score 9):

Changing preferences and running, `defaults -currentHost read -g` shows you what changes are being written. I was going to write up a short bash script to automate it, but it looks like I was beaten to the punch:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      

mappingplist=com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping

if [ $1 == "emacs" ]; then
    echo "Switching to emacs modifiers"
    defaults -currentHost write -g $mappingplist '(                              
                {                                                                
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 4;                                   
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2; },                                
                {                                                                
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 12;                                  
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10;                                  
        },                                                                       
                {                                                                
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2;                                   
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 4;                                   
        },                                                                       
                {                                                                
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 10;                                  
            HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 12;                                  
        })'


else
    echo "Switching to default modifiers"
    defaults -currentHost delete -g $mappingplist
fi
```

> The script takes one argument, if the
>   argument is emacs, then it swaps
>   command and control, if the argument
>   is anything else it restores the
>   defaults.
>
> http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=949280

Comment: It doesn't seem to work from me here with Snow Leopard, but it's clearly a step in the right direction.

Comment: @pith... what's the `-g` flag do?  I didn't see that in the man page for `defaults`.  Also, this looks like it's swapping two sets of values: 4 with 2 and 10 with 12, yet there are only two modifiers that change.  Can you elaborate, or did you simply look at the output but don't know what they actually represent? (At first I suspected four key codes--two on the left, two on the right--but they don't appear to be key codes, at least not as reported by the keyboard driver.)

Comment: I do the mappings as you suggest but it doesn't seem to take effect although in the UI it appears mapped.
Only doing it via UI seems to work...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/changing-modifier-keys-from-the-command-line) with the [PCKeyBoardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html). It also allows you to use Emacs keys in any Mac app, including the ones not using Cocoa such as MS apps.

Answer (score 2):

From ["Updating modifier key mappings through defaults command tool"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13598/updating-modifier-key-mappings-through-defaults-command-tool):

`defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1133-50475-0 -array '<dict><key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key><integer>0</integer><key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key><integer>2</integer></dict>`

Change `1133` and `50475` to the vendor and product IDs shown by `ioreg -n IOHIDKeyboard -r`. `src 0` and `dst -1` would disable <kbd>caps lock</kbd>.

`defaults -currentHost write -g` modifies:

`~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist`

You have to log out and back in to apply changes. If the values are strings (like in the answer by @pithyless), the changes are shown in System Preferences but they don't have any effect.

[Values of keys](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060825072451882):

```
-1 none
0 caps lock
1 left shift
2 left control
3 left option
4 left command
5 keypad 0
6 help
9 right shift
10 right control
11 right option
12 right command
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to swap **Right Command** with **Right Option** keys only.

When I setup global **Command** and **Option** swap in System Preferences... > Keyboard > Modifier Keys..., there is following config in the system (which works as expected):

```
$ defaults -currentHost read -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-591-0
(
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771299;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771298;
    },
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771303;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771302;
    },
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771298;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771299;
    },
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771302;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771303;
    }
)
```

But when I modify it, to swap only **Right** side as below - it doesn't work:

```
$ defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-591-0 '(
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771303;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771302;
    },
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771302;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771303;
    }
)'
```

It's because values are written as strings not integers. You can see that using:

```
$ plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-591-0</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key>
            <string>30064771303</string>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key>
            <string>30064771302</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key>
            <string>30064771302</string>
            <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key>
            <string>30064771303</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So the right way to update the setting is using XML format:

```
$ defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-591-0 -array \
'<dict>
    <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key>
    <integer>30064771303</integer>
    <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key>
    <integer>30064771302</integer>
</dict>' \
'<dict>
    <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key>
    <integer>30064771302</integer>
    <key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key>
    <integer>30064771303</integer>
</dict>'
```

At the end, you have to log off and log in again.

Comment: Did you get this to work I cant tell?  Is a reboot required maybe?

Comment: Ah... Yes. You have to log off & log on again.

Comment: I am trying to answer this question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280855/changing-right-hand-command-alt-key-order-to-be-like-a-windows-keyboard  Can you chat maybe?  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat  I tried running your last command and it doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: First of all remove Karabiner-Elements and adapt keyboard code (1452-591-0) and key codes (30064771302, 30064771303) to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Combining a few answers together I came up with this script that seems to work (**mapping Caps-lock to Control**).

```
$ keyboard_id = "$(ioreg -n IOHIDKeyboard -r | grep -e VendorID\" -e ProductID | tr -d \"\|[:blank:] | cut -d\= -f2 | tr '\n' -)"
$ defaults -currentHost write -g "com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.${keyboard_id}0" '(
{
  HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2;
  HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0;
})'
```

**Only problem that it doesn't seem to take any effect... :(**

**I'll update if it I get it to work.**