# Changing right-hand Command & Alt key order to be like a Windows keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macos

I would like to switch the Right Command (⌘) Key order with the Alt Key under the System Preferences (to be just like Windows) but there appears to be no option under System Preferences.

Does anyone know how to move these keys' locations using [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) or some other software?  In this case we would swap the right-hand Alt and Command keys.

[image: Modifier Keys in System Preferences]
<sub>(source: [tekrevue.com](https://cdn1.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/mac-system-preferences-modifier-keys.png))</sub>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apple's Technical Note [TN2450](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) describes how to remap keys.  It is important to know that Right Command is also Right GUI.  Running the following command will switch **Right Command** and **Right Alt** (if you also want to do the Left Command and Left Alt, refer to the technical note to get the hex values and the Python code below to do the `or` operation).

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":
    [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000e7,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x7000000e6},
     {"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000e6,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x7000000e7}]
}'
```

The table at the bottom of the Technical Note has a list of hex values for each key.  To generalize the above answer to [switch any keys (at least is macOS Sierra)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control/283253#283253), you must `or` the hex value from that list together with `0x700000000`.  The following Python code demonstrates one way to do this.

```
In [1]: def convert(val):
   ...:     int_val = int(val, 16)
   ...:     ref = '0x700000000'
   ...:     int_ref = int(ref, 16)
   ...:
   ...:     return hex(int_ref | int_val)
   ...:

In [2]: r_alt = '0xE6'

In [3]: print(convert(r_alt))
0x7000000e6
```

Comment: Works for Mojave as well.

Comment: Works on Catalina as well. And is better than  Karabiner-Elements as it does not interfere with Logitech Options - that I use for an external keyboard. Unfortunately, this setting disappears after shutdown. @steven-c-howell do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @Pawel you could try to setup an automator app like here: https://superuser.com/a/465506/1415759

Comment: Remember that this only works if you haven't used the "modifier keys" option in the macOS settings to switch keys (control, option, command, ...).

Answer (score 11):

A more general and user-friendly approach is to use [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md), which is a version of Karabiner that works on Sierra.

Karabiner-Elements allows for your specific use case (that's how I use it) in addition to almost any other kind of key remapping.

My configuration looks like[image]

Comment: I'm currently using Karabiner Elements to map right command key to right option (alt) key. I suggest you download and test - maybe the author just hasn't updated your issue (there are over 400 issues logged).

Comment: Could you post your configuration then?  That is what I stated in the question.

Comment: Here you go, I added an image to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to swap **Option (Alt)** with **Command** or **Control** with **Command**?

See [Changing modifier keys from the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/changing-modifier-keys-from-the-command-line/277544#277544)

Comment: Right Command and Right Alt should be swapped